# How to get the data of the inserted multiple rows in Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, eloquent

So I manage to save multiple datas at once using laravel `model::insert(array(...));`

example data

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'organization' => '1',
    'status' => false,
    'project' => '1',
    'act_date' => '2016-11-23 08:19:06',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'organization' => '1',
    'status' => false,
    'project' => '1',
    'act_date' => '2016-11-23 08:19:06',
  ),
)
```

What I want is to get the data, or the id *at least* of the inserted array. This data must also contain the multiple id's (`array({ data[0].id=>1 }, { data[1].id=>2 })`) corresponding to the number of data's inserted.

The problem with `model::insert(array(...));` is that it returns `true` when successful and `false` otherwise.

`model::create(array(...));` returns the data of the inserted row, but doesnt support multiple row inserts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would really recommend you to use `create()` method if you want to get an ID of each inserted row.

But if you really want to use `insert()` you could try this (method has it's own disadvantages though and I wouldn't use it):

```
model::insert($array);
$lastIds = model::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(count($array))->pluck('id');
```

Comment: great, one thing tho what disadvantages are you refering? @Alexey

Comment: @HardSpocker in theory you can get wrong last IDs inserted by another query on high load system. I guess it depends on DB type you're using and you better ask this question to DB guys. So, I would recommend you to use loop and multiple `create()->id`

Comment: is there another way? i mean looping multiple `create()->id` takes too much time and resources if the array is large enough.

Comment: @HardSpocker I don't know about any other way. Looping `create()` will usually not take a lot of resources, because usually inserting queries are executed not very often. I know one `insert()` is faster, but still, I would use multiple `create()`, especially on a high load system.

Comment: from docs: "For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: It's not perfect, but it's seems to be the best solution at this time.

Answer (score 0):

> I think this method is helpful for you

```
 $data = array(
        array (
    'organization' => '1',
    'status' => false,
    'project' => '1',
    'act_date' => '2016-11-23 08:19:06',
  ),
        array (
    'organization' => '1',
    'status' => false,
    'project' => '1',
    'act_date' => '2016-11-23 08:19:06',
  ),
///////
    );

    Model::insert($data);
    DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

re: @Alexey Mezenin's concerns about returning the wrong rows on a high load system.

What works for me is to generate a random string, or you could use the current timestamp, and add that to each row I'm inserting, I call this "insert_key", then after the batch insert has finished, I query the DB for all records that have my "insert_key", now I have all the newly inserted ID's

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    $savedIds = [];
    foreach($data as $record) {
        $savedIds[] = Model::insertGetId($record);
    }
    $savedRecords = Model::whereIn('id', $savedIds)->get();
```